# implementation of polynomial in sparse matrix using a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, sparse-matrix

Given a 2 degree polynomial,How to implement it in a sparse matrix using a doubly linked list?

Comment: Welcome to [SO]!  What have you tried?  What language are you looking to use?  What are your applications?  We need more information before we can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct node{
   int term;
   int coefficient;
   struct node* next;
   struct node* previous;
}Node;

Node matrix[3];
```